# The Depravity of Produce

Tags: pattern, enigmatic-puzzle

Having read *[The Grapes of Wrath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Grapes_of_Wrath)*, I started wondering why grapes were the only fruit assigned a vice.  Why can't oranges, or watermelons, or even pomelos grapple with the same licentiousness and iniquity that the poor grapes have to deal with on a daily basis?

I began exploring what the sins of other fruits might be, and made myself a list.  In doing so, I discovered that [John Steinbeck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Steinbeck) had it wrong!  He apparently should have titled his book *The Grapes of Envy*.

Here is the list I came up with.  Can you determine how I linked each fruit with its particular vice?

> ***apples of spite***
>   ***apricots of blasphemy***
>   ***bananas of pride***
>   ***blueberries of intolerance***
>   ***boysenberries of faithlessness***
>   ***cantaloupes of pettiness***
>   ***coconuts of complacency***
>   ***grapes of envy***
>   ***kiwis of apathy***
>   ***mangoes of sloth***
>   ***nectarines of jealousy***
>   ***pears of avarice***
>   ***persimmons of perversion***
>   ***plums of cowardice***
>   ***pomegranates of gluttony***
>   ***quinces of egotism***
>   ***tangerines of profligacy***

**Bonus A**:  What sin might be associated with `pomelos`?
**Bonus B**:  What fruits might be subject to the sin of `manipulation`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The sum of their character values `a=1, b=2, ..., z=26` is the same for the fruit and the sin.

I found this by observing that

> each fruit and sin have similar number of letters, and guessing the answer from there, writing up code to check.

Comment: I also noticed that similarity between fruit and sin but I didn't think to explain it that way.

Comment: `watermelons` and `manipulation` both sum to 145.

Comment: `pomelos` of `sedition` works.